# Django Template tag to allow bold and italic elements

Tags: django, templates, bold, italic, templatetag

Django has a template tag that allows you to remove certain html tags from being displayed in stored data.

The django documentation gives an example. Any b or span tags are removed. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#removetags

```
{{ value|removetags:"b span"|safe }}
```

However, I'm wondering if there is a good way to do the inverse.  For example, blacklist all tags except for tags specified.  In my case, I just want to allow bold and italic tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your own template tag using [bleach](https://github.com/jsocol/bleach).

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own template tag based on original [removetags](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L467) and this regexp:

```
>>> import re
>>> tags = ['b', 'i']
>>> tags_re = u'(%s)' % u'|'.join(tags)
>>> striptags_re = re.compile(ur'</(?!{0}).*?>|<(?!/)(?!{0}).*?>'.format(tags_re), re.U)
>>> value = '<b>foo</b><i><p>bar</b>'
>>> striptags_re.sub(u'', value)
u'<b>foo</b><i>bar</b>'
>>> value = '<b>foo</b><p>bar</p>'
>>> striptags_re.sub(u'', value)
u'<b>foo</b>bar'
```

Comment: Using regular expressions for parsing HTML is highly discouraged.

Comment: I'm not going to parse HTML. The OP asked about removing tags and I did it. You can see that my code works like original django tag

Comment: Thank you for your San4ez.  It's a nice and simple solution.