# Django Template – Mark only certain HTML tags as safe

Tags: html, django

I have the following use case: a user should be able to enter in HTML input and it should be displayed as such. However, it can only contain `<br>, <italic>, <strong>, <ul> or <li>` tags.

I know about the safe filter, but that way it would allow every HTML input and be prone to XSS.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You should "walk" over the AST tree and validate this. But I think you should validate when *entering* data, not when *rendering* data.

Comment: i am agree. The text from user should be cleaned before any other use. Anywhere. Anytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10454527/7109869), one can use [`bleach`](https://github.com/mozilla/bleach).

Start by defining a list of the tags one wants to allow by overriding the default [`ALLOWED_TAGS`](https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clean.html#allowed-tags-tags)

```
ALLOWED_TAGS = ['br', 'italic', 'strong', 'ul', 'li']
```

Then, use [`bleach.clean()`](https://bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clean.html#bleach.clean) to remove any other HTML tags that are not allowed

```
user_input = '<p>an <strong>example</strong> for SO</p>'
cleaned_user_input = bleach.clean(user_input, tags=ALLOWED_TAGS)
```

This will remove the `p` tag from the `user_input`.

Answer (score 0):

We can make a validator that only allows certain tags, for example with *BeautifulSoup*:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible


@deconstructible
class HtmlValidator:
    def __init__(self, tags=()):
        self.tags = tags

    def validate(self, node):
        if isinstance(node, Tag):
            if node.name not in self.tags:
                raise ValidationError(f'Tag {node.name} is not a valid tag')
            for child in node:
                self.validate(child)

    def __call__(self, value):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(value, 'html.parser')
        for child in soup:
            self.validate(soup)
```

Then we can add such validator to the model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(
        max_length=1024,
        validators=[HtmlValidator(tags={'br', 'italic', 'strong', 'ul', 'li'})],
    )
    # …
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer and sorry for the *really* late reply, this just came up again and I need to start working on it.
However, what if I can't decide what's stored in "content"? I really only have control over what's actually rendered. Is there any way to mark_safe the tags I specify, but just display the other ones as plain text?